# How to setup circleci tests for algorand sandbox project?

Tags: node.js, config, circleci

I am working on an algorand project with NodeJS script and using sandbox for our development.

Note: We are using algorand indexer also along with sandbox but no contracts.

For development purpose we can test easily using jest but when I try to automate it with circle CI then it fails in testing stage.

Here is my .circleci/config.yml file::

```
version: 2.1

orbs:
  node: circleci/node@5.0.0

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/node:17.5.0
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: echo "build project"
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm run build
  linting:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/node:17.5.0
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: echo "Linting project"
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm run lint
  test:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/node:17.5.0
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: echo "Running tests"
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm run test

workflows:
  test_build:
    jobs:
      - linting
      - build
      - test:
          requires:
            - build
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algorand sandbox (https://github.com/algorand/sandbox) is itself using Docker and docker-compose. As such, it cannot easily be used directly in another docker container.

You can see a discussion there:
https://github.com/algorand/sandbox/issues/84

From there you have two choices:

1. Use a machine executor instead of a docker executor in Circle CI: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/executor-types/ / https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/docker-to-machine/. This allows you to have access to docker and run sandbox.
2. Since sandbox is just a wrapper around https://github.com/algorand/go-algorand and https://github.com/algorand/indexer, you can manually extract this part and run a node without sandbox for your tests.

PS: In general, I would recommend asking Algorand-related questions on https://forum.algorand.org which is more active than stackoverflow for such questions.